# Show radio schedule based on date and time PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to create radio schedule to show what is currently playing with an image. I have so far to show it on the right days, but how do narrow it further to show between specfic time, say 5:30am - 9:00 am? See code below;

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');
// echo date('H:i:s A w');

if (date('w') > 0 && date('w') < 6){ ?>
<div class="current-radio">
<img src="http://gandlp.com/radio/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/5pm.jpg">
<h5>Scott Fox and Kat Callaghan In The Morning</h5>
<p><small>Weekdays from 5:30am-9am</small></p>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

basically this:

```
if (date('G:i') > '05:30') && (date('G:i') < '09:00'))
```

normally comparing times as strings doesn't work, but in this particular case, it's (somewhat) acceptable - you're dealing with time values in most-significant first ordering and "military" format (24hour). Even though it's doing string comparisons, it just "works".

Comment: Hello,Thanks, it does work. However they have different schedules of weekdays vs weekends what to do then?

Comment: then start building up more logic. if (certain date) { filter for this day } else if (some other day) { apply other day filters}, blah blah blah

Comment: Hi would you be able to provide an example? I am not too proficient with PHP just trying to get this little snippet to work